# How to reset the error state in an ErrorBoundary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I can't figure out a good way to reset an `ErrorBoundary` from outside the component. Due to the UI design of the application, I have a "Retry" button outside of the `ErrorBoundary` component which when clicked should reset the error state within the `ErrorBoundary`.

For example, I have a fairly standard `ErrorBoundary`:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>;
    }
    return this.props.children; 
  }
}
```

And in my main App, I have something along this:

```
const BadComponent = (props) => {
   return (
      <button onClick={() => {
         throw new Error("Something happened!")
      }}>Trigger Error</button>
   );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {
         // How to reset ErrorBoundary here when button is clicked?
      }}>Retry again</button>

      <ErrorBoundary>
        <BadComponent />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  )
}
```

From the example above, I have a `BadComponent` that will throw an error when it's clicked. I also have a Retry button in my main `App` component that is supposed to reset the error state within `ErrorBoundary` so that it re-renders the children (which is the `BadComponent`) again.

However, the error state is within the `ErrorBoundary` component and I can't directly control the error state from outside of it. I can't pass a props into `ErrorBoundary` for the error state too because *the error in this case is caught and managed by and within the `ErrorBoundary` component and not by the `App` component*.

If I do use a prop just to indicate whether the error should be reset, I will have to maintain the error state and another error prop within the `ErrorBoundary` and make sure they are consistent which feels awkward.

So, how can I reset the error state of the `ErrorBoundary` component? It will be great if there is an example of how I should do it.

Comment: Set `hasError` to `false` where you feel is appropriate. Based on your conditional statement it would instead of the error message, show the actual children. You need to decide what your logic needs to be in terms of user interaction or business flow for when to clear that error based on `hasError` state value

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky But `hasError` is a state within `ErrorBoundary`. The "retry" button is outside of the `ErrorBoundary` component. How can I set the `hasError` state from outside the `ErrorBoundary` component?

Comment: Disregarding `ErrorBoundary` specifically, how would you handle managing state across different levels of components such as sibling components or parent/child component?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I'm aware that I could have controlled states in `App` and pass as props into `ErrorBoundary` which is the child component and then set the states internally based on the props. What I'm thinking is, however, the errors are caught inside the `ErrorBoundary` component and then it updates the error state inside the `ErrorBoundary` component itself. The `App` component won't catch the error and hence I don't think it is able to control an error state and pass it as a prop to the `ErrorBoundary`?

Comment: If you need to have reset control detached from ErrorBoundary, use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) for state/setState.